# Foursquare venue image not displaying

Tags: foursquare

I have created an app in foursquare, I have the client_id and client_secret key. I need all the venues details. I can only get the venue info, but cannot get the image linked to it. 
Please help me . Thanks in advance

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&v=20161201

Comment: Kindly note that the link you provided does not open and seems to need some credentials. Kindly try to provide the code linked to the issue you are asking about and the language use in your code so you may get better feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the venue details response there is a photos object under `response['photos']` that contains an array of venue photos. To construct the photo url we have documentation [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo.html).

From the docs:

> To assemble a resolvable photo URL, take prefix + size + suffix, e.g.
>   https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/general/300x500/2341723_vt1Kr-SfmRmdge-M7b4KNgX2_PHElyVbYL65pMnxEQw.jpg.
>
> size can be one of the following, where XX or YY is one of 36, 100,
>   300, or 500.
>
> - XXxYY
> - original: the original photo's size
> - capXX: cap the photo with a width or height of XX (whichever is larger). Scales the other,    smaller dimension proportionally
> - widthXX: forces the width to be XX and scales the height proportionally
> - heightYY: forces the height to be YY and scales the width proportionally

Comment: Documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

you can get photos of a specific venue by this API 
http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos?limit=5&client_id=Client_Id&client_secret=Client_Secret&v=20161107